# Google Coral : hide kernel boot messages

Tags: google-coral, edge-tpu, mendel-os

How to hide kernel boot message on the Google Coral ?

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
10.0
```

but i can't find the grub file (i tried, like for debian, /etc/default/grub ... nothing) to edit and add "quiet" (like for a regular Ubuntu/Debian), then regenerate grub :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

embeded linux usually uses uboot instead of grub as it is too large. Specifics on how to customizing kernel should take more researches, however, you can add `loglevel=0` to the kernel command line to eliminate some kernel messages.

Download boot.txt:

```
$ curl https://coral.googlesource.com/uboot-imx-debian/+/refs/heads/master/debian/boot.txt\?format\=TEXT | base64 --decode | tee boot.txt > /dev/null
```

Install mkimage:

```
$ sudo apt install u-boot-tools
```

Make your necessary changes in the cmdline="" line, for this example, we need to add "quiet loglevel=0":

```
cmdline=<preexsisting> + quiet loglevel=0
```

compile to boot.scr:

```
$ mkimage -A arm -T script -O linux -d boot.txt boot.scr
```

replace old boot image file

```
$ mv boot.scr > /boot
```

Reboot and the new kernel params should be loaded.

share  edit  delete  flag